# How to update tableView cell's labels when every time i enter new value in textField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, variables, uitextfield

How to update tableView cell's labels when every time i enter new value in textField?

---

```
@objc func doneClicked() {
        view.endEditing(true)

        //MARK: - ФОРМАТТЕР
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale.current
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 3
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6

         if let text = textField.text, let number = formatter.number(from: text) {

            atmosfera = number.doubleValue

            print(atmosfera)


        }
    }
```

This func is button for toolbar in keyboard. When i press "Done" my keyboard close and value is updated.

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "resultCell") as! resultTableViewCell


            cell1.nameResult.text = converters[indexPath.row]
            cell1.labelResult.text = String(convertatmo[indexPath.row] * atmosfera)


            return cell1


    }
```

This is my cells.

---

Every time when I press Done button on keyboard I save a new value to `atmosfera` var.
I want to update my `labelResult.label`s. How I could do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `reloadData` instance method of the `tableView` any time you want to refresh the whole table

```
 if let text = textField.text, let number = formatter.number(from: text) {

        atmosfera = number.doubleValue

        print(atmosfera)

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `tableView.reloadData()` after you update the `atmosfera` var, that will reload the tableView with the new data.